# Java multi-level aes de/encrypting fails

Tags: java, encryption, base64, aes, encryption-symmetric

I have been tasked with decrypting a file in Java that has been encrypted using the following criteria:

Encrypting:

`

```
byte[] masterKey;
    if (Base64.decode(config.getProperty("encrMasterKey")) != null) {
        masterKey=aes.decrypt(Base64.decode(config.getProperty("encrMasterKey")),"password");
    } else {
        masterKey = aes.keyGeneration();
        byte[] encrMasterKey = aes.encrypt(masterKey, keyderivation("password"));
       writeToConfigFile("encrMasterKey", Base64.encode(encrMasterKey));
    }
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(masterKey, "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
    byte[] cypherText = aes.encrypt(myJSONString,masterKey);'
```

What works:

1. i can encrypt/decrypt with AES, both with byte[] and from password derivated keys(keyderivation("password"))
2. i can save and load correctly from the config file. In fact i tested and the generated Base64encoded( masterKey )is the same  as the Base64.encode(aes.decrypt(Base64.decode(config.getProperty("encrMasterKey")),"password")))

What doesnt:

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(masterKey, "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
```

At cipher.init java throws an illegal key or default parameter error.

I would really appreciate a hint on this one, keeps bugging me for days now and i cant seem to fix it...

Best wishes

Comment: Got it, stupid mistake, the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files were missing on this machine, so the keygeneration returned a bad key which produced the cipher.init error.

Comment: We've got a few dupes regarding that, so it would probably be wise to delete the question.

Comment: @user2107478 can you document the steps that led you that missing Policy Files were causing this. It will certainly help others in similar situations

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900542/java-security-invalidkeyexception-illegal-key-size)

Comment: I wrote an if-block so that the code would warn a user if there is no JCE USJ etc. installed `int max = Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES");
 if (max == 128) {
     System.out.println("Max keylenght is: "
      + Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES")
      + ". Please install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html ");
 }`