# InvalidKeyException Illegal Key Size when i export runnable jar file

Tags: java, security, jar

I have got an error:

```
InvalidKeyException Illegal Key Size
```

Then I download 2 files(local_policy, US_export_policy) and put it in

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\security

everithing worked fine. But when i export project to

> Runnable jar file

and then open this jar i have error in my app :

```
InvalidKeyException Illegal Key Size
```

Why it happen? I dont know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by two ways:

### First way:

You have already put 2 files(local_policy, US_export_policy) in

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\security
```

You also need to put it in

```
C:\Program Files\Java\lib\security
```

### Second way:

You need to install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files which is available at [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

If you don't then the keysize is limited due to US export laws.

### Resource Link:

[InvalidKeyException Illegal key size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862800/invalidkeyexception-illegal-key-size)