# AES-256-CTR Encryption in node JS and decryption in Java

Tags: java, node.js, security, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encode in nodejs and decryption for the same in nodejs works well. But when I try to do the decryption in Java using the same IV and secret, it doesn't behave as expected.

Here is the code snippet:

Encryption in nodeJs:

```
   var crypto = require('crypto'),
   algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
   _ = require('lodash'),
   secret = 'd6F3231q7d1942874322a@123nab@392';

  function encrypt(text, secret) {
    var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    console.log(iv);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, new Buffer(secret), 
    iv);
    var encrypted = cipher.update(text);

    encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);

    return iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted.toString('hex');
}
var encrypted = encrypt("8123497494", secret);
console.log(encrypted);
```

And the output is:

```
<Buffer 94 fa a4 f4 a1 3c bf f6 d7 90 18 3f 3b db 3f b9>
94faa4f4a13cbff6d790183f3bdb3fb9:fae8b07a135e084eb91e
```

Code Snippet for decryption in JAVA:

```
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = 
   "94faa4f4a13cbff6d790183f3bdb3fb9:fae8b07a135e084eb91e";
        String seed = "d6F3231q7d1942874322a@123nab@392";

        decrypt(s, seed);
    }

    private static void decrypt(String s, String seed)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        String parts[] = s.split(":");
        String ivString = parts[0];
        String encodedString = parts[1];
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

        byte[] secretBytes = seed.getBytes("UTF-8");
        
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(hexStringToByteArray(ivString));
        
        /*Removed after the accepted answer
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(secretBytes);*/ 
        
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES");
        
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, ivSpec);
        byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(hexStringToByteArray(encodedString));

        System.out.println(new String(output));
    }
}
```

Output: �s˸8ƍ�

I am getting some junk value in the response. Tried a lot of options, but none of them seem to be working. Any lead/help is appreciated.

Comment: Well...  You're outputting the IV and ciphertext hex encoded in NodeJS.  And you're printing the output raw in Java.  Why would you **expect** them to be the same?  I get the feeling you didn't write this code and you've just copied and pasted it from somewhere without attempting to understand it.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark: The Java code is for *decryption*; it's supposed to produce the same output as the *input* to the JS encryption code, which is a plain (non-hex) text string. Anyway, I've verified that the output of the JS code can be decrypted using the `openssl enc` command-line tool (which is not that much of a surprise, since the node.js crypto module is based on OpenSSL), so the bug (and/or standards mismatch) must be on the Java side.

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj: This question and its answers are two and a half years old. Copies of them have already spread to lots of SO mirror sites and archives, and you'll never get them all changed. That key is on the web to stay, and all you're doing by trying to edit it out is attract more attention to it. I suggest you change the key in your project ASAP instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your JS code, you're using the 32-character string `d6F3231q7d19428743234@123nab@234` directly as the AES key, with each ASCII character directly mapped to a single key byte.

In the Java code, you're instead first hashing the same string with MD5, and then using the MD5 output as the AES key.  It's no wonder that they won't match.

What you probably *should* be doing, in both cases, is either:

1. randomly generating a string of 32 bytes (most of which won't be printable ASCII characters) and using it as the key; or
2. using a [key derivation function (KDF)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40757/key-derivation-functions-kdf-what-are-main-purposes-how-can-they-be-used) to take an arbitrary input string and turn it into a pseudorandom AES key.

In the latter case, if the input string is likely to have less than 256 bits of [entropy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/378/what-is-entropy) (e.g. if it's a user-chosen password, most of which only have a few dozen bits of entropy at best), then you should make sure to use a KDF that implements [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) to slow down brute force guessing attacks.

---

Ps. To address the comments below, MD5 outputs a 16-byte digest, which will yield an AES-128 key when used as an AES SecretKeySpec.  To use AES-256 in Java, you will need to provide a 32-byte key.  If [trying to use a 32-byte AES key in Java throws an InvalidKeyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862800/invalidkeyexception-illegal-key-size), you are probably using an old version of Java with a limited crypto policy that does not allow encryption keys longer than 128 bits.  As described [this answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3864276), you will either need to upgrade to Java 8 update 161 or later, or obtain and install an unlimited crypto policy file for your Java version.

Comment: The Key in real case in supposed to be a client specific key, which is it to be used for encryption for their many fields in their data. And so, I can't change it for each single encryption.
Also, If I do not use hash the same string with MD5, I get InvalidKey Exception
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size

Comment: @AshishPandey: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862800/invalidkeyexception-illegal-key-size. Apparently, you may need to either upgrade Java or install a new crypto policy to enable AES-256 en/decryption. MD5 outputs a 128 bit (= 16 byte) digest, which will create an AES-128 key when used as an AES SecretKeySpec.

Comment: Following this, to update the version to update 161, and updating the crypto.policy=unlimited in setting as suggested, makes the decryption work well. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

In the Java code you are taking the MD5 hash of `secret` before using it as a key:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(secretBytes);
SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES");
```

Whereas, in your NodeJS code, you don't do this anywhere.  So you're using two different keys when encrypting and decrypting.

Don't copy and paste code without understanding it.  Especially crypto code.

Comment: In node, to use this algorithm, it explicitly asks that the key length must be 32 bytes. While in Java, while decrypting, it tells me that the key size is illegal. Can you check and tell, what is it that I am missing here ? I used digest so that it doesn't throw an error with that.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same task (but with 128, it easy to adapt for 256), here is working Java/NodeJs code with comments.

It's additionally wrapped to Base64 to readability, but it's easy to remove if you would like.
Java side (encrypt/decrypt) :

```
import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class
import java.util.Base64;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class MyClass
{
    private static void log(String s)
    {
        System.out.print("\r\n"+s);
    }

    public static SecureRandom IVGenerator() {
       return new SecureRandom();
    }

  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void  main(String[] args)
  {
    String valueToEncrypt = "hello, stackoverflow!";
    String key = "3e$C!F)H@McQfTjK";

    String encrypted = "";
    String decrypted = "";

    //ENCODE part
    SecureRandom IVGenerator = IVGenerator();
    byte[] encryptionKeyRaw = key.getBytes();
    //aes-128=16bit IV block size
    int ivLength=16;
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
    //generate random vector
    IVGenerator.nextBytes(iv);

    try {
        Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKeyRaw, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        //encrypt
        byte[] cipherText = encryptionCipher.doFinal(valueToEncrypt.getBytes());

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(ivLength + cipherText.length);
        //storing IV in first part of whole message
        byteBuffer.put(iv);
        //store encrypted bytes
        byteBuffer.put(cipherText);
        //concat it to result message
        byte[] cipherMessage = byteBuffer.array();
        //and encrypt to base64 to get readable value
        encrypted = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipherMessage));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    //END OF ENCODE CODE
    log("encrypted and saved as Base64 : "+encrypted);

    ///DECRYPT CODE : 
    try {
        //decoding from base64
        byte[] cipherMessageArr = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);
        //retrieving IV from message
        iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherMessageArr, 0, ivLength);
        //retrieving encrypted value from end of message
        byte[] cipherText = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherMessageArr, ivLength, cipherMessageArr.length);
        Cipher decryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKeyRaw, "AES");
        decryptionCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKeySpec , ivSpec);
        //decrypt
        byte[] finalCipherText = decryptionCipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        //converting to string
        String finalDecryptedValue = new String(finalCipherText);
        decrypted = finalDecryptedValue;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    log("decrypted from Base64->aes128 : "+decrypted);
    //END OF DECRYPT CODE

  }
}
```

It could be easy be tested by online java compilers (this example prepared on https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler).

NodeJs decrypt side :

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const ivLength = 16;
const algorithm = 'aes-128-ctr';

const encrypt = (value, key) => {
    //not implemented, but it could be done easy if you will see to decrypt
    return value;
};

function decrypt(value, key) {
    //from base64 to byteArray
    let decodedAsBase64Value = Buffer.from(value, 'base64');        
    let decodedAsBase64Key = Buffer.from(key);
    //get IV from message
    let ivArr = decodedAsBase64Value.slice(0, ivLength);
    //get crypted message from second part of message
    let cipherTextArr = decodedAsBase64Value.slice(ivLength, decodedAsBase64Value.length);
    let cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, decodedAsBase64Key, ivArr);
    //decrypted value
    let decrypted = cipher.update(cipherTextArr, 'binary', 'utf8');
    decrypted += cipher.final('utf8');
    return decrypted;
}
```